# error - 'expected primary expression before...' in function definition (C++)

Tags: c++, structure, function-definition

Trying to run this in an online compiler I get the error - 'expected primary expression before '.' ' in function definition on all 4 structure members: height, width, length, volume. In Visual studio the error is ' 'box' illegal use of this type as an expression. What could be the cause?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct box

  {

      float height;
      float width;
      float length;
      float volume;
  };


void display(box amazon);

int main()

{
    box amazon

    {
         10, 10, 10, 10
    };

    display(amazon);

    return 0;

}

   void display(box amazon)

    {
        cout<<"Box height: "<<box.height;
        cout<<"Box width: "<<box.width<<"Box length: "<<box.length<<"Box volume: "<<box.volume;
    }
```

Comment: `box` is the name of the type. Your variable is called `amazon`

Comment: in display function `box.` should be `amazon.` youre using the type as if it was a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `display` function you have to change `box`, which is the type, with `amazon`, which is the object

```cpp
       void display(box amazon)
    
        {
            cout<<"Box height: "<<amazon.height;
            cout<<"Box width: "<<amazon.width<<"Box length: "<<amazon.length<<"Box volume: "<<amazon.volume;
        }
```